# Какую версию Yii посоветуете?

Tags: yii, yii2, сравнение

Собираюсь создавать базу данных для ведения бизнеса.
Какой Yii фреймворк посоветуете? 1 vs 2?

Программировал процедурно, перехожу на ООП -> Yii framework
я думаю на счет 1, т.к. документации больше.
English = false;

Пожалуйста поясните.

Comment: Для второй версии документации достаточно. В вашем случае не нужно тянуть legacy код и переучиваться, поэтому выбирайте вторую версию.

Comment: Yii1 старый, Yii2 полностью написанный с нуля, новый. Выбирайте Yii2. Laravel очень схож с Yii2, тоже хорош.

Comment: Yii2 как более свежий и перспективный

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если выбирать из двух версий, то, конечно, вторую. Если абстрагироваться от личного мнения, то первая писалась в совсем другом мире, когда PHP и вправду в 99% случаев означал стек apache/nginx-php-mysql, и в сторону шагать особо не было смысла, кроме того, AR в первой открыто проигрывает AR во второй (в первой версии приходилось вручную заниматься созданием записей связей Many-To-Many).

Если же привлечь мое личное мнение и посмотреть на весь внешний мир, то ни одну ищ версий Yii брать не стоит. Есть целая плеяда более интересных и достойных фреймворков, у авторов которых получается писать хороший инструмент, самый популярный и ненапряжный из них - это, пожалуй, Laravel.